# PHP multi dimensional array get comma separated string value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array structure:

```
[prod_prop] => Array
        (
            [45375] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 129|3|Mid-length
                )

            [45374] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 130|3|Long
                    [1] => 129|3|Mid-length
                )

            [45373] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 131|3|
                    [1] => 130|3|Long
                    [2] => 129|3|Mid-length
                )

        )
```

I want to loop through each parent number and output comma separated string of first part of second level array

So, how can I get a sting separated value for each number so desired result is as follows:

45375 -> returns 129

45374 -> returns 130,129

45373 -> returns 131,130,129

This is my current code which returns everything in the comma separated array not what im after:

```
 foreach($_POST['prod_prop'] AS $prop_ids) {
            $list = implode(",",$prop_ids);    
            echo $list;
        }
```

Returns:
131|3|131|3|,130|3|Long131|3|,130|3|Long,129|3|Mid-length 131|3|,130|3|Long,129|3|Mid-length

Comment: Then go for it! Try it, maybe you will surprise yourself :D

Comment: I've tried but not sure how identify the values in the 2nd level of the array? I can loop though fine for each top level

Comment: Then show us your attempt!

Comment: Hmmm i think i see the error of my ways! Each element is a string already with | seperater this should be another array instead

Comment: It would make the coding for sure easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($_POST['prod_prop'] as $prop_ids) {
    $list = join(',', array_map(
        function ($id) { return current(explode('|', $id)); },
        $prop_ids
    ));    
    echo $list;
}
```

Comment: This works well , however i should probably due a sub array rather than explode on the string containing |. thanks

Comment: How does this exactly work? does map to elements that contain |

Comment: An array_map is the same as `$res = array(); foreach ($arr as $i) $res[] = func($i);`, where `func` is the `function` given above. Play around with it.

Comment: last question i'm struggling to get the parent KEYs 45375 ,45374, 45373 etc. Trying key($_POST['prod_prop']) but it stays on the first key?

Comment: `foreach ($_POST['prod_prop'] as $key => $prop_ids)`

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this with using these functions:- `end()`,`explode()`,`trim().` Use the code below

```
$last = end($_POST['prod_prop']);
 foreach($_POST['prod_prop'] AS $prop_ids) {
foreach($prop_ids as $s){
$list .= ",".explode("|",$s)[0];
}
if($prop_ids==$last){
echo trim($list,",")."";
}
else{
echo trim($list,",").",";
}


        }
```

Try it for yourself.Hope this helps you.

Comment: This isn't really my desired result this brings back: 131|3|131|3|,130|3|Long131|3|,130|3|Long,129|3|Mid-length 131|3|,130|3|Long,129|3|Mid-length

Comment: @darvey it was just a hint, if you want your desired result use implode with explode. Wait posting your answer

Comment: @darvey Updated my answer..., maybe this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you scroll through array, `implode()` its values, and apply regex onto it?

```
$res = Array();
foreach($_POST["prod_prop"] as $bID=>$bLists) {

   $str = implode(",", $bLists); // get list of values comma separated

   preg_match_all("/(^|,)(\d+)/", $str, $m); //get all digits, which follow string start or comma

   if (Count($m[1])) { // if value found - store it in $res array
      $res[$bID] = implode(",", $m[1]);
   }
}
```

One note: I'm not sure about syntax of regex in PHP. In javascript the following works

```js
var str = "131|3|,130|3|Long,129|3|Mid-length";
$('#result').html(str.match(/(^|,)(\d+)/g));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use-case for [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php).  Try this:

```
foreach($_POST['prod_prop'] as $id => $properties) {

    $result = array_reduce($properties, function($val, $item) {

        return $val . ',' . substr($item, 0, strpos($item, '|'));
    });

    echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use iterated calls of `strtok()` calls on each subarray to isolate the substring before the first pipe, then `implode()` the truncated elements before echoing.

```
foreach ($_POST['prod_prop'] as $prop_ids) {
    echo implode(',', array_map(fn($v) => strtok($v, '|'), $prop_ids)) . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
> $stateId = Array (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [id] => 9
>             [state_id] => 81
>             [rto_id] => 82
>             [is_active] => 1
>         )
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [id] => 10
>             [state_id] => 82
>             [rto_id] => 83
>             [is_active] => 1
>         )
> 
> );
> 
> $stateIds = implode(",", array_column($stateId, "state_id"));
> 
> echo $stateIds;
> 
> 
> ***Result : 81,82***
```

Comment: Answers are generally improved by including some sort of explanation with the code.

Comment: Please explain what you did there so the questioner knows what you did.